# Polymer: selected item not showing up in paper-listbox

Tags: javascript, polymer, dropdown

I am looking for a way to correctly select a element from the dropdown in a paper-listbox. With this code, I can't select the one element that is in the dropdown. The element appears in the dropdown, but doesn't appear as the selected element when it is clicked on.

Here is the code :

```
`<paper-dropdown-menu>
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{myElem}}">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[myElems]]">
      <paper-item value="[[item.name]]">[[item.name]]</paper-item>
    </template>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>`
```

The value of {{myElem}} is "aaa-bbb". (got this value by doing $0.selected on the paper-listbox element).

The value of [[item.name]] is "aaa-bbb". (got this value by doing $0.value on the paper-item element).

The value of myElems is simply an array, containing one element.

Comment: Your approach should work. Did you import all the dependencies, including paper-item.html? Here's a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zTyPsE8E9mpz1HV9PZ3j?p=preview).

Comment: yes i did :) but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with `selectedItem` attribute of [paper-dropdown-menu](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu) element.

Here is my code. Notice `_itemSelected` listener:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">

<dom-module id="stackoverflow-43054191">
  <template>

      <paper-dropdown-menu id="dropdown">
        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{myElem}}">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[myElems]]">
            <paper-item value="[[item.name]]">[[item.name]]</paper-item>
          </template>
        </paper-listbox>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'stackoverflow-43054191',

      properties: {

        myElems: {
          type: Array,
          value: [{'name': 'aaa-bbb'}]
        }

      },

      listeners: {
        'iron-select': '_itemSelected'
      },

      _itemSelected() {
        var which = this.$.dropdown.selectedItem.textContent;
        console.log(which); //"aaa-bbb" when it's selected
      }

    });
  </script>
```